# rename extracted files in BIM360 Plan folder

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

seems you cannot rename extracted sheet files of Revit model OOTB in BIM 360 Plan folder, is it doable via API?

Comment: Sorry for our late response. It looks true PATCH Item (with new display name) cannot work with BIM 360 Docs :(  I checked the status of the internal ticket （FDM-2432） , it is still Open. I also double tested, it will throw the error when PATCH item for BIM360 Docs file. I posted an inquiry in that ticket to ask for status

Comment: in the same time, I found one post  in which my colleague Eason shared a workaround in 2019 https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-api-forum/bim-360-docs-unable-to-rename-file/td-p/9079103. Not elegant, but looks the way right now.

Comment: thanks Xiaodong, is Eason's workaround basically deleting old and create new? and does API limitation also apply to files in "Project Files" folder? i mean you also cannot rename file in "Project Files" folder via API, currently it can be done manually, just files in "Plans" folder cannot be renamed manually

Comment: no it is not deleting the old, it is to create a new version with any of of the previous version model. you can notice the call encloses copyFrom={URL_ESCAPED_SOURCE_VERSION_URN}, which means re-use the existing version model. e.g. if  v5 for current version, then create v6 but v6 model is same to v5 model, while with renamed..